# Altium error: Nets containing multiple input ports. What does this error mean?

Tags: altium

I am relatively new to Altium, and I am running into the following errors when compiling my schematic:

1. Net SDI contains multiple Input Ports (Port SDI,Port SDI)
2. Net CLK contains multiple Input Ports (Port CLK,Port CLK)

What I am trying to do is connect multiple sheets to the same signals, SDI and CLK. Am I doing something wrong? It is a flat hierarchy, I have set the scope to "Flat (Only ports global)". Below are two sheets of my schematic that uses SDI and CLK signals

Sheet1:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/CGcwAeG.jpg]

Sheet2:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/AllFW51.jpg]

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer right now, but I suspect it's related to the choice for global net names vs local net names.

Answer (score 19):

With "Flat (Only ports global)" scope selected, "...net labels are local to each sheet; they will not connect across sheets. All ports with the same name will be connected, on all sheets."  - [Altium "Multi-Sheet Design"](http://www.altium.com/files/training/Module%205%20-%20Multi-Sheet%20Design.pdf)

This seems like it should be OK for what you are trying to do, but I think in this type of design setting, there must be a 1:1 relationship of Input and Output port. In the flat design case, the input ports *are* connected to each other, hence the "multiple input ports" error. Here are a couple things you could try:

1. **Switch to a Hierarchical design**

   This requires you to use a Top sheet to control the design hierarchy. Review *"5.1.3  Constructing the top sheet"* in the previously mentioned training module. For what it's worth, all of my designs are of this design setting.
2. **Change Input ports to Bidirectional**

   This may make the error go away (due to your project's Connection Matrix), but it might not make sense from a real-world viewpoint. The CLK/SDI lines are most certainly not bidirectional. This might cause problems when you are in a design review and have to explain why you've marked everything as bidirectional.
3. **Edit the connection matrix**
   Stick with your flat design setting, but tell Altium to shove it by editing the Error/Warning connection matrix:
   [image: Screenshot of Altium Project connection matrix]

   Now multiple input ports will only be reported as a warning, not a show-stopping error.

Comment: +1 for "Switch to Hierarchical design". Having all port connections *have* to go through the top layer schematic makes inter-sheet connections SO much more readily understandable.

Comment: I vote for the "tell altium to shove it" option. In flat designs involving busses having multiple output ports connect to one input port is perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

I like the answer by @dext0rb but turning off logical errors/warnings for all ports could cause problems later on.

So just turn off the error on the specific net using "Generic No ERC"

[image: Altium Generic No ERC Location]

and then

[image: Altium Generic No ERC Port-Port Connection Option]

Answer (score 0):

I prefered to create the ports as Unspecified in this case. While the directional arrows are still held (plus colour coordination) from their previous Input/Output format.

Unspecified allows the user to create multiple inputs and outputs for these ports.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to change electrical type of pads in schematic symbols to passive.

[image]