# Net PWMA_IC3 contains Multiple Input Ports(PWMA,PWMA)

Tags: altium, input, error, compiler

[image: SOLVED snap]
I have to give two different PWM Input to my two Gate driver ICs my design.

1. i have taken two output ports PWMA and PWMB hoping, I will make them 180° apart in phase in programming.
   2)I want to give HIN pin PWMA as input and LIN of gate driver IC. However, i have two gate driver ICs. I want to give them both PWMA and PWMB to their HIN and LIN in inverse fashion so that my MOSFETs don't get shorted.

I keep getting the Error containing multiple input ports since they have name, or so i believe. Is the anyother way to connect these ports?
PS: I have two sheets one has the circuti, one has the MCU and it is flat design.

[image: error]

Comment: I've never used Altium, but would make sense if you can't give the same net multiple names. As it is, you have connected the offpage connector PWMA to both "PWMA_IC3" and "PWMA_IC4". Try removing the net names "PWMA_IC3" and "PWMA_IC4". And the same for PWMB ofcourse.

Comment: Hello Kenny, I had actually tried to remove the net line. But, No result. I don't know any othe way than using the same port name to connect the MCU output to both of my Gate driver IC.

Comment: @rafi could you show exact error you get? Put screenshot or copy the text.

Comment: @esehic so error: NetPWM_IC3 contains multiple input ports(port PWMA, port PWMA)
NetPWM_IC3 contains multiple input ports(port PWMB, port PWMB)

Comment: @Klas-Kenny solution 2 works from this :https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/55670/altium-error-nets-containing-multiple-input-ports-what-does-this-error-mean
Question is,  Does it mean they are getting the same signal fro mCU, since two of FETS need to be turned on at the sametime. Is it going to be a problem for PCB design?

Comment: @rafi You are not allowed to have two ports. Delete two left ports, and change the left net names to have same name as right. Just use PWMA and PWMB net names.

Comment: @esehic are you saying i should just put net two labels PWMA and PWMB for four pins. and delete all the ports in my sheet1. would that suffice?This two ports have output with same name from sheet2(PICO/MCU). That is  how i wanted to connect them.

Comment: You should have only one port per sheet. You should use ports to create connectivity between sheets, and use net labels to create connectivity inside sheet. Delete two ports connected to IC4. Change net labels connected to IC3 to have same name as port name. Change net labels on IC4 to have the same name as net labels on IC3. You could still get errors, It depends on your Altium settings.

Comment: @esehic that's what i did, unfortunately i found the errors above. I have added the pictures above. What could have caused it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134125/discussion-between-esehic-and-rafi).

Answer (score 1):

**@esthetic was correct** with the:
You should have only one port per sheet. You should use ports to create connectivity between sheets, and use net labels to create connectivity inside sheet. Delete two ports connected to IC4. Change net labels connected to IC3 to have same name as port name. Change net labels on IC4 to have the same name as net labels on IC3. You could still get errors, It depends on your Altium settings.

I have added the corrected photo of my design above for others to checkout let me know.